# How to add approved reviews on Product page

Tags: magento, php

I want to show in my product page the **approved reviews for the product**.
So I am editing this file:

> mytemplate/default/catalog/product/view.phtml

I tried adding this to the view.phtml file but nothing is showing up:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?>
```

Can you suggest a way of adding approved reviews on product page? I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all write this code in `catalog.xml`

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml"/>
```

then

write this code in your `view.phtml`

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?>
```

it will solve your problem...

Comment: Thanks Keyur! It works ... Can I add also "the Add your review" functionality? Now it shows only the reviews..Is that possible ?

Comment: means you have to add Add your review link?

Comment: Not only the link.The whole form of adding a comment..Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

add this line in template/review/product/view/list.phtml file 
this line add  anywere u want

$this->htmlEscape($_review->getStatusId())=='1'){ echo ' Approved Review';

Comment: Thank u ankit I will try it also!